# laravel model object to string for javascript

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Please help me clean this monstrosity! I'm trying to get my array of users from Laravel collection to a JavaScript variable.

This is the only way I got this working:

```
<script>
var obj = {
    users: [<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) { echo $users[$i]->getObject(); if ($i + 1 < count($users)) { echo ','; } } ?>],
}
</script>
```

which gives me the correct output:

```
users: [{"id":1,"first_name":"A","last_name":"A","birthday":"1970-02-12","gender":"M","username":"aa","email":"a@a.com","permissions":null,"activated":true,"activated_at":null},{"id":2,"first_name":"b","last_name":"b","birthday":"1982-01-10","gender":"M","username":"bb","email":"b@b.com"}]
```

I am using [Robclancy/Presenter](https://github.com/robclancy/presenter) which means the object when sent to the view ends up being a presenter so I need to get the object back with `$user->getObject();`

---

From my controller `$users = User::all();` which returns a Collection of User objects.
[image]

I tried to do

```
<script>
var obj = {
    users: <?php echo $users; ?>,
}
</script>
```

but that just gives me

```
var obj = [{},{}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, it was the issue with presenter not knowing how to convert the object, robclancy helped me out.
https://github.com/robclancy/presenter/issues/18

Answer (score 8):

Eloquent has a built-in `toJson` method:

```
var obj = {
    users: <?php echo $users->toJson(); ?>
};
```

Comment: that gives me var obj = [{},{}];